# Difficulty with \onslide in beamer

Tags: pandoc, beamer

I'm using pandoc to generate my beamer slides. Currently pandoc isn't smart about context and uses the same command for a pause in all situations. This causes some problems.

In particular, if you put in a \pause on a slide after an itemized list, incrementally revealed, as pandoc now does, that will insert an extra slide after the list is finished. If you use \onslide<+-> instead of \pause, you get the desired behavior of no extra slide.

However now you have the problem that a simple slide with \onslide<+-> instead of \pause doesn't pause.

Is there a single pausing command that would work in these various contexts?

Here's a simple document that shows it. The "text after desired pause" bit appears right away with \onslide<+->, which **I think** is the correct behavior, so it won't work in this context, though \pause does what I'm after:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

text before text

\onslide<+->

text after desired pause

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

text before list

\onslide<+->

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\tightlist
\item
  one
\item
  two
\item
  three
\end{itemize}

\onslide<+->

text after pause after list

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try to ask on [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) or maybe tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've put it up on tex.stackexchange.com.